# Condensed ui-grid table

Tags: angular-ui-grid

What's the best way to get something like bootstrap's table-condensed in ui-grid tables?

I've tried playing around with `.ui-grid-cell`'s `height` and `.ui-grid-cell-contents`' `padding` but then the scrolling doesn't match the size and it causes strange behaviour when editing cells.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not edit row's height by changing `css` since it's style is calculated in real-time.

You can change `gridOptions.rowHeight` and then everything should work just fine.

You can though change padding and font size, as you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TKRRG5gGswMZHYmtxQD0?p=preview) where I changed both `rowHeight` and padding/font-size.

You can see more info on `rowHeight` on the official docs, [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#properties_rowheight).